# Table lock upon SET TABLESPACE in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What type of table lock is acquired when you move a table (or rather a partition) from one tablespace to another in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Should I execute NO INHERIT first to detach it from the master table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table (and its toast table and toast index, if they exist).

It does not matter if the table inherits from another table or not.

If the table has any indexes and you want to move those too, you'll have to explicitly move them with `ALTER INDEX ... SET TABLESPACE ...`.